# How to import *.pyd file python (Linux machine)

Tags: python, linux

I've a .pyd file which i'm able to import in windows machine , but unable to import in my linux machine .

Is there a way I can import ?

I don't have the source file for the *.pyd file FYI.

Thanks

Comment: Not without using a Windows version of Python.

Comment: what do you mean by windows version of python . i am in Linux machine . AFAIK, there is no windows version of python for Linux .

Comment: Of course there isn't. But there's WINE.

Answer (score 2):

.pyd file is basically a windows dll file. Please refer to http://docs.python.org/faq/windows.html#is-a-pyd-file-the-same-as-a-dll

So you can't import it in Linux. You might need a alternative edition for Linux.

Comment: The .pyd file is for windows only,  so there is no way to import it in Linux.